# Stream Tweets using Tweepy on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am looking to stream tweets on a continuous basis, based on some filter criteria and store them in a database. I already have a Python script to accomplish this using Tweepy. What I would like to know is, which AWS service would be the best for my use case, i.e. to run the Python script continuously? I know that Lambda has a time limit, so is the only option I have to use an EC2 instance?

To be clear, what I want to do is to run my Python script continuously on some service (maybe an EC2 instance) and have it feed data to a Firehose stream. The stream will then deliver these tweets to a database.

The script itself is quite simple and does not require much computing resources.

Comment: ec2 or lightsail (being predefined instances) are good options. lambda has a million free hits per month (give or take memory/time usage), so if you are hitting the api less frequently even though it runs 24/7 you might get away with setting a cron job on lambda to run every few seconds and ping the api. seems excessive since lightsail is $5/month.